# how to select all reference of same word only inside a class in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In this code, VS Code IDE, suppose I want to select all the `a1` simultaneously but inside function def only . `Shift+Ctrl+L` will select all the reference of a1. And `Ctrl+D` will select the next reference.

```
def division(self):
    a1=float(self.a1/self.a2)
    a1=a1*100
    a1=int(a1)
    a1=a1/100
    return float(self.a1/self.a2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- select the text in which you want to do the replace
- `Ctrl+F` open find dialog
- Select - Find in Selection (3 horizontal lines)
- enter the name of the variable: `a1`
- `Alt+Enter` - select all occurrences
- type the new name

To select the class/function fast, if it is big

- collapse the class with the **fold** arrow
- select the folded class line
- unfold the class

Or use refactoring

- put cursor on an occasion of `a1`
- `F2` to rename variable in context

Or with `Select Next`

- select first occurrence of `a1`
- press `Ctrl+D` as often as it appears in the function/class
- use `Ctrl+K Ctrl+D` if you select an occurrence you don't want but there is next one
- use `Ctrl+U` if you select one to much
- type new name

Comment: Personally I prefer __`[ CTRL ]` + `[ D ]`__.

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV When you have a big piece of text (>100 occurrences, maybe code) Ctrl+D gets tedious

Comment: I probably shouldn't assume, though I am assuming anyways, that its not C++, because for C++ the obvious way to go is the Refactor tool, but for something like TS/JS, if the text is truly unique you can just hold-down __[CTRL] + [D]__  and it will select 100 instance in less than 5 seconds. If you get an error after you edit them, or cut them. Just create an empty text file paste everything you selected in it, and what ever it is you selected that you didn't intend to will stickout like a sore thumb. The other way you can go is to just C&P the entire class into a text document & F2 it.

Comment: Its not uncommon, as u stated, to have to select several cases. When using an editor u have to be careful though, because the only way to get a true refactor tool that I know of, is w/ the Microsoft C++ tools extension, everything else selects, but doesn't let you review what you have selected before you make the change. [CTRL] + [D] recursively selects through each instance  of the word you are targeting, that's why I use it, but like I said, if it does get tedious, I just copy & paste the output in a text file & F2 or CTRL+F2 depending on the circumstance.